# transform Vertical information into horizontal

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to have this transformation in vba

[image]

And to inderstend better i shere with you this picture 
[image]

Now i have another column and i should have this information in the new table, but i don't find haw to make this?
[image]

Comment: Use `SUMIFS` have you tried anything so far, do you want in VBA, if so share code?

Comment: Record a macro creating a pivot table.

Comment: Why is prix only 18 for client3?  shouldn't it be 22?

Comment: yes, @xQbert it was an error, yes it should be 22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I did was setup your sample data and then record a macro and saved recorded macro generated below.

Now note: if your data is larger then you may want to record using key strokes to put cursor at beginning of table and then at the end of the table or "Define data as a table" and use the table.... but this gives you the general idea.

```
Sub Macro1()
' Macro1 Macro

    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "Sheet1!R1C1:R10C4", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable _
        TableDestination:="Sheet1!R13C1", TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion _
        :=xlPivotTableVersion14
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Cells(13, 1).Select
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Customer ")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable1").PivotFields("Group"), "Sum of Group", xlSum
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Price")
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    Columns("C:C").ColumnWidth = 5.71
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Price").Subtotals = Array( _
        False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False)
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Sum of Group")
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 2
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable1").PivotFields("Price"), "Sum of Price", xlSum
    Range("E14").Select
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Sum of Price").Caption = _
        "Prix"
    Range("B18").Select
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").RowGrand = False
End Sub
```

Which then results in:

[image]

to handle the new column: Id combine the values in the raw data.  if however you are after something different I would need to see an example of the desired output.

[image]

Comment: Now i have another column and i should have this information in the new table, but i don't find haw to make this?

[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSytU.png)

Comment: repeat steps above to create a pivot table. adding the additional column as a row label

Comment: I tried but i don't have the good result,
 I have got this [table]https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQRQL.png

Comment: That's how the pivot works.  However if you need the Client1 and ville1 to be on the same line, you could combine the cells on the original raw data using a new column and use it for your `lignes`